# Determine if zip code contains numbers only

Tags: sql, db2

I have a field called zip, type char(5), which contains zip codes like

```
12345
54321
ABCDE
```

I'd like to check with an sql statement if a zip code contains numbers only.

The following isn't working

```
SELECT * FROM S1234.PERSON
WHERE ZIP NOT LIKE '%'
```

It can't work because even '12345' is an "array" of characters (it is '%', right?

I found out that the following is working:

```
SELECT * FROM S1234.PERSON
WHERE ZIP NOT LIKE ' %'
```

It has a space before %. Why is this working?

Comment: It depends the Zip code? Are you talking about US zip codes? british? canadian? French? Also, there are countries that do not use zip codes for addresses like South American coutries.

Comment: `%` matches any string of characters.

Comment: What version of DB2 are you running, and on what platform?  DB2 10.5 on Linux does not exhibit the behavior you're seeing in the second query (both queries return 0 rows).

Comment: There's also an option of using the XQuery `matches()` function, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489752/determine-if-zip-code-contains-numbers-only/23492839#23492839

Answer (score 3):

If you use SQL Server 2012 or up the following script should work.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Zip VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('12345')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('54321')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('ABCDE')


SELECT *
FROM   @t AS t
WHERE  TRY_CAST(Zip AS NUMERIC) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: try_cast() function is an amazing tip! And works for many databases.

Answer (score 0):

Using answer from [**here to check if all are digit**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489703/db2-how-to-check-if-varchar-field-value-has-integers)

```
SELECT col1,col2
FROM
   (
     SELECT col1,col2,
                 CASE
                     WHEN LENGTH(RTRIM(TRANSLATE(ZIP , '*', ' 0123456789'))) = 0 
                     THEN 0 ELSE 1
                 END as IsAllDigit
     FROM S1234.PERSON
   ) AS Z
WHERE IsAllDigit=0
```

**DB2** doesnot have regular expression facility like **MySQL** `REGEXP`

Comment: That's False. DB2 DOES have regular expression support via xQuery! http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfnmat.html http://angocadb2.blogspot.fr/2014/04/regular-expressions-in-db2.html

Answer (score 0):

USE ISNUMERIC function;
ISUMERIC returns 1 if the parameter contains only numbers and zero if it not

EXAMPLE:
 SELECT * FROM S1234.PERSON
 WHERE ISNUMERIC(ZIP) = 1

Your statement doesn't validate against numbers but it says get everything that doesn't start with a space.

Comment: Doesn't exist for DB2. Wasn't my question. I want to know why my last statement IS working.

Comment: Your statement doesn't validate against numbers but it says get everything that doesn't start with a space

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you ZIP code is a USA zip code, composed by 5 numbers.

```
db2 "with val as (
 select *
 from S1234.PERSON t
 where xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches(\$ZIP,''^\d{5}$'')') as integer) = 1
)
select * from val"
```

For more information about xQuery:fn:matches: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfnmat.html

Comment: Not what the OP is asking - he wants to know _why_ it's working.

Comment: However the title say: "Determine if zip code contains numbers only". So my answer is still valid. Why ' %' is working is another question, and the title or that question should be changed!

Answer (score 0):

mySql does not have a native isNumberic() function. This would be pretty straight-forward in Excel with the ISNUMBER() function, or in T-SQL with ISNUMERIC(), but neither work in MySQL so after a little searching around I came across this solution...

```
SELECT * FROM S1234.PERSON 
WHERE ZIP REGEXP ('[0-9]')
```

Effectively we're processing a regular expression on the contents of the 'ZIP' field, it may seem like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut and I've no idea how performance would differ from a more simple approach but it worked and I guess that's the point.

Comment: Not only is the OP not looking for a query that does work (he wants an explanation of why the query he does have is working), he's also not using MySQL.  This syntax isn't supported on DB2, and would cause a syntax error.  (Depending on version there may be regex support, but it's indirect).

Answer (score 0):

I have made more error-prone version based on the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211270/565525, added intermedia result, some examples:

```
select 
      test_str
    ,                  TRIM(TRANSLATE(replace(trim(test_str), ' ', 'x'), 'yyyyyyyyyyy', '0123456789'))
    , case when length(TRIM(TRANSLATE(replace(trim(test_str), ' ', 'x'), 'yyyyyyyyyyy', '0123456789')))=5 then '5-digit-zip'  else 'not 5d-zip' end is_zip
from (VALUES 
        ('  123  '  )
        ,('  abc  ' )
        ,('  a12  ' )
        ,('  12 3  ')
        ,('  99435 ')
        ,('99323'   )
    ) AS X(test_str)
;
```

The result for this example set is:

```
TEST_STR 2        IS_ZIP
-------- -------- -----------
  123    yyy      not 5d-zip
  abc    abc      not 5d-zip
  a12    ayy      not 5d-zip
  12 3   yyxy     not 5d-zip
  99435  yyyyy    5-digit-zip
99323    yyyyy    5-digit-zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if there's a difference between lower case and upper case. Numerics and special chars will look the same:

```
SELECT *
FROM S1234.PERSON 
WHERE UPPER(ZIP COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI ) = LOWER(ZIP COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example for the case where you'd want to check zip codes in a range. You could use this code for inspiration to make a simple single post code check, if you want:

```
if local_test_environment?
  # SQLite supports GLOB which is similar to LIKE (which it only has limited support for), for matching in strings.
  where("(zip_code NOT GLOB '*[^0-9]*' AND zip_code <> '') AND (CAST(zip_code AS int) >= :range_start AND CAST(zip_code AS int) <= :range_finish)", range_start: range_start, range_finish: range_finish)
else
  # SQLServer supports LIKE with more advanced matching in strings than what SQLite supports.
  # SQLServer supports TRY_PARSE which is non-standard SQL, but fixes the error SQLServer gives with CAST, namely: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'US-19803' to data type int.
  where("(zip_code NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND zip_code <> '') AND (TRY_PARSE(zip_code AS int) >= :range_start AND TRY_PARSE(zip_code AS int) <= :range_finish)", range_start: range_start, range_finish: range_finish)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regex.

```
SELECT * FROM S1234.PERSON
WHERE ZIP REGEXP '\d+'
```

Comment: OP is not looking for how to find digits, but why his query is finding the answer.