# SQL case "if error"

Tags: sql, db2

How can I use case or something else to handle errors so my query does not crash. For example I would like to select 1 column and 1 "formula" based on that column... something like this:

```
select column01 ,
       case ('if column01 is number then integer(column01) else 'error'')
from table01
```

I would basically like the second column to convert column01 into integer, which already works for me fine... but if converting causes an error I would like to see the word 'error'

or at least have the second column say 'OK' when the convertion is possible and 'error' when it is not.

I am using DB2

Comment: You want a `case` expression. Note that its different return types must be compatible.

Comment: That `case` doesn't really do anything useful. All `case` subexpression must return the value of the same data type, therefore the value returned by `integer(column01)` is cast right back to `varchar` in order to be compatible with the character literal `'error'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2- How to check if varchar field value has integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489703/db2-how-to-check-if-varchar-field-value-has-integers)

Comment: What you're looking for, in the general sense, is an equivalent to Some/None behavior from functional programming.  Your best bet is possibly using `null` as the "None" value here, which has the benefit of flowing through lots of other calculations if you're messing with additional columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select column01,
CASE
  WHEN LENGTH(RTRIM(TRANSLATE(column01, '*', ' 0123456789'))) = 0 
  THEN INTEGER(column01)
  ELSE 'Error'
END as ColumnType
from table01
```

Comment: @RobertPitrone - Note that my version of DB2 (iSeries), at least, appears to be swallowing the word 'Error' and returning something invalid (but not erroring out).